# From Spring Web Flow to Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow

So, I have a Spring Web Flow where I have a Model object completely formed. And, I have a Service that stores the values obtained from the flow, to my Database. Is there a way I can bind the Model object stored in the flow, AND the Controller that manage the storing of the values of that model in the Database?

Thank you.

Comment: Bind means what do you want to do? You need access of the flowScoped form in controller?

Comment: I ended up calling directly the Service from an evaluate in my flow.xml. I pass the model and the RequestContext, from where I can get the session, and some values I needed that are stored there.